# Serving different charsets per virtual host

Tags: centos, php, httpd.conf, charset

On a centos Server 6.5, apache 2.2.15 is it possible to server multiple charsets to different virtual hosts?

I know that setting the default Charset is done by adding into the httpd.conf file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

However some of the websites we have need to be encoded using ISO-8859-1 but the other websites that are served by Symfony need to be encoded with UTF-8. Is it possible to add a default charset per virtual host or does this need to be done using .htaccess files?

Comment: Whatever you put in .htaccess files can be put into separate site vhosts.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the default charset per directory or vhost, see [httpd.apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_charset_lite.html#charsetdefault).

In short:

```
<Directory /some/dir>
    CharsetDefault ISO-8859-1
</Directory>
```

You'll also need to ensure that the `mod_charset_lite` module is enabled.

Comment: Is it the same for Apache 2.4?

Comment: Yes, follow the httpd.apache.org link and change the 2.2 in the URL to 2.4, it's basically the same.